# how to add fields to library column in share Point Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

I am new to SharePoint. I have created a column in the document library. but I am unable to add the field to the column while adding a document. Is there any solution add field to the column while adding the document.

I have one solution after adding the document. I am opening the library in a quick view and editing the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking in the Document Library settings to see if Content Types are being used.

If they are, it could be that the column has not been added to the Content Type you are using.

If there is only a single content type (probably called 'document'), click on it and see if your column is included as part of the content type.

If this does not help, another thing to check for is custom coding e.g. jquery, which could be hiding the column.  To check this, select edit page > then look for a script webpart.

FOR REFERENCE

A [Microsoft link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-or-customize-a-site-content-type-27eb6551-9867-4201-a819-620c5658a60f) on Content Types.